# Cannot find module '../dialog' (Electron fatal error)

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

In electron, I encounter the following error:

```
module.js:440
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../dialog'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/opt/App/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:47:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:386:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.get [as dialog] (/opt/App/resources/electron.asar/browser/api/exports/electron.js:35:14)
    at process.<anonymous> (/opt/App/resources/electron.asar/browser/init.js:64:31)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:276:26)
```

It happens on a child process spawn that fails in Linux. Strange because I do have a try catch block around that, yet it still results in an uncaughtexception, as seen in the code in browser/init.js from electron.asar:

```
// Don't quit on fatal error.
process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
  // Do nothing if the user has a custom uncaught exception handler.
  var dialog, message, ref, stack
  if (process.listeners('uncaughtException').length > 1) {
    return
  }


 // Show error in GUI.
  dialog = require('electron').dialog
  stack = (ref = error.stack) != null ? ref : error.name + ': ' + error.message
  message = 'Uncaught Exception:\n' + stack
  dialog.showErrorBox('A JavaScript error occurred in the main process', message)
}
```

As said, my code is in a try catch:

```
try {
  server = childProcess.spawn(java, ["-jar", "App.jar"], {
    "cwd": serverDirectory,
    "detached": true
  }, function(err) {
    console.log("in callback");
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log("here we are");
  console.log(err);
}
```

But neither the callback nor the catch block is reached. Any ideas what is going on here and why the default dialog module cannot be found?

Answer (score 1):

I found same error with `electron 1.6.2`

Figured it was due, when closing the application an error occur and electron want to display it in a dialog, maybe the close process has started and electron can't load this module, anyway I add:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron');
```

in `main.js`, no more error in console instead a dialog the error, I can fix it, After that I let the require just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly...

If by "default dialog module", you mean the electron dialog API, then you can require that like so: `const { dialog } = require('electron')`. (Or in pre-1.0 versions simply `require('dialog')`. See https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md

Also the try/catch needs to be around the require in the child process. The try/catch you have is around the spawning of the child process in the parent. That require is failing in an entirely different node.js process, so it's not caught in the parent process that spawned it. It sounds like your child process code might work better if it looked like:

```
try {
  const dialog = require('dialog');
} catch(e) {}
```

Also, if `childProcess.spawn` is referring to the core node module `child_process`, that doesn't accept a callback function. See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Can you share the code from your child process? That might help more.

Comment: Hi, I'm not requiring the dialog myself. It happens in electron.asar in browser/init.js -- this is due to some uncaught exception, electron tries to show a dialog box but fails to require the dialog module, hence the error. My callback to spawn was due to it being an exec statement before, yes, I can remove that. I'm not sure what you mean by having the try catch elsewhere? The require for the childProcess variable is at the very top of the page ; const childProcess = require("child_process");

Comment: The child process itself is a java executable. However, I also have server.stderr.on("data", function() {}) etc callbacks. The whole thing is in a try catch block.